# How do I fetch data from multiple firebase databases using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from two firebase databases below following this firebase doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/

```
     // Initialize Firebase
var marketplaceconfig = {
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
databaseURL: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(marketplaceconfig);


var secondaryAppConfig = {
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
databaseURL: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig);

var secondary = firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");
```

I referenced the secondary database as follow

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
if (user) {
     PersonalAsstDatabase = secondary.database();


    var BusinessesId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    // var selectedJob = JobId.value ;

    var deptref = PersonalAsstDatabase.ref('/Businesses/' + BusinessesId + '/Inventory/');

}
})
```

but I keep getting this error

> code: "app/duplicate-app", message: "Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)."

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to initialize the default app twice:

```
firebase.initializeApp(marketplaceconfig);
firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig);
```

If you want to initialize a second non-default app, you're going to have to give it a name by passing a second argument to [initializeApp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#.initializeApp):

```
firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");
```

Be sure to also read the docs on [initializing multiple apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#initialize_multiple_apps) to better understand how to proceed.